# Totally Confused on "Cannot Find Symbol"

Tags: java

Ol' newbie here again ... I'm getting this message cannot find symbol for all of the files that I've defined. I've copied in below the source code that's relevant to my problem:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
// * LU6.2 Transceiver 
 *---------------------------------------------------------------*/
package APPC_LU62.java ; 

import java.nio.* ;

import java.nio.channels.* ;

import COM.ibm.eNetwork.cpic.* ;

import java.io.* ;

public class LU62XnsCvr extends Object 
 { 



      // Define I/O Files 
   static File Rqst_File = new File("C:\\APPC_LU62\\LU62XC\\CA_DMV\\Rqst_File.txt") ;   
   static File Resp_File = new File("C:\\APPC_LU62\\LU62XC\\CA_DMV\\Resp_File.txt") ;
   static File Logr_File = new File("C:\\APPC_LU62\\LU62XC\\CA_DMV\\Logr_File.txt") ;
   static File Mesg_File = new File("C:\\APPC_LU62\\LU62XC\\CA_DMV\\Mesg_File.txt") ; 


 }



public static void main(String args[]) 
   {
       if (args.length < 10) 
         { 
           System.out.println("LU62XCE0013: Missing or Invalid Runtime Path and/or APPC Partner Name") ;
           System.out.println("LU62XCE0013: This Process will be Terminated")  ; 
           sys_return = 13 ; 
           SysEnd( sys_return ) ;
         } 

       String Runtime_Path = args[0] ;     // pick up the runtime path for the request and response files
       String APPC_Partner = args[1] ;     // and the APPC Partner LU Name
       PartLULen = APPC_Partner.length() ; // get the length of the partner luname
       if ( PartLULen > 8 )
         {   
          System.out.println("LU62XCE0013: APPC Partner Name Length Greater Than 8 bytes ") ;
          System.out.println("LU62XCE0013: This Process will be Terminated")  ; 
          sys_return = 13 ; 
          SysEnd( sys_return ) ;
         } 

       ConnectFiles() ; 

       ProcessRequests() ; 

       sys_return = 0 ;
       SysEnd( sys_return ) ; 

   }  // end of main routine 




public static void ConnectFiles() 
   {
          //Connect the LU62XC Message File 
     FileOutputStream(Mesg_File) ;
     FileChannel MesgChnl  =  Mesg_File.getChannel();
     ByteBuffer  Mesg_bufr = ByteBuffer.allocate(128) ; 


         // Does RequestFile exist? then Process it...
     if ( !Rqst_File.exists() )
       {   // Request File DOES_NOT exist 
         message_data.append("LU62XCE0113: Request File = ") ; 
         message_data.append(Rqst_File) ; 
         message_data.append(" Not Found...This Process will be Terminated") ;
         SendMesg() ;
         sys_return = 113 ; 
         SysEnd( sys_return ) ; 
       }     


            // Connect files to program via I/O channels and buffers 
     FileInputStream(Rqst_File) ;
     FileChannel RqstChnl  = Rqst_File.getChannel() ;
     ByteBuffer  Rqst_Bufr = ByteBuffer.allocate(400) ; 

     FileOutputStream(Resp_File) ;
     FileChannel RespChnl =  Resp_File.getChannel();
     ByteBuffer  Resp_Bufr = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024) ; 

     FileOutputStream(Logr_File) ;
     FileChannel LogrChnl =  Logr_File.getChannel();
     ByteBuffer  Logr_bufr = ByteBuffer.allocate(428) ; 

            // Initialize log header fields
     RqstHdr = RqstFlag.getBytes() ;  // convert string to byte array 
     RespHdr = RespFlag.getBytes() ;  // convert string to byte array 

   }   // end subroutine ConnectFiles
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:153: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method FileOutputStream(java.io.File)
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
     FileOutputStream(Mesg_File) ;
     ^
[loading java\nio\channels\FileChannel.class(java\nio\channels:FileChannel.class)]
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:154: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getChannel()
location: class java.io.File
     FileChannel MesgChnl  =  Mesg_File.getChannel();
                                       ^
[loading java\nio\ByteBuffer.class(java\nio:ByteBuffer.class)]
[loading java\nio\Buffer.class(java\nio:Buffer.class)]
[loading java\lang\CharSequence.class(java\lang:CharSequence.class)]
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:171: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method FileInputStream(java.io.File)
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
     FileInputStream(Rqst_File) ;
     ^
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:172: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getChannel()
location: class java.io.File
     FileChannel RqstChnl  = Rqst_File.getChannel() ;
                                      ^
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:175: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method FileOutputStream(java.io.File)
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
     FileOutputStream(Resp_File) ;
     ^
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:176: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getChannel()
location: class java.io.File
     FileChannel RespChnl =  Resp_File.getChannel();
                                      ^
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:179: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method FileOutputStream(java.io.File)
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
     FileOutputStream(Logr_File) ;
     ^
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:180: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getChannel()
location: class java.io.File
     FileChannel LogrChnl =  Logr_File.getChannel();
```

Appreciate any and all help with regard to what I'm doing wrong ...

Thanks

Guy "If I was doing this in assembler I'd be done" Rich   ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't understand "cannot find symbol"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841904/dont-understand-cannot-find-symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmmm there doesn't exist any method called FileOutputStream. If you were trying to create a FileOutputStream (cos there's a class called like that), try to use something like:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Resp_File);
```

and so on. I saw at least 2 occurrences of this error.

Comment: Now looking at it on detail (thanks to @Oli for the edit, btw), there are actually 3:Rqst_File, Resp_File and Logr_File.

Comment: Thanks very much for your insight .... I'll have to review the examples in the IBM guide on using New I/O ....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to call a method called FileInputStream()

Perahps you meant to do `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(...)`?