# "cannot find symbol" despite correct variable name

Tags: java, javac

In the following code snippet  I really don't understand why the compiler is issuing
the "cannot find symbol" error message.

```
public class LU62XnsCvr extends Object 
{       
  // these two variables (among many others) are declared here as "public" 
   static StringBuffer message_data = new StringBuffer(); 
   static File Mesg_File = new File("C:\\...\\Mesg_File.txt"); // path snipped

   public static void SendMesg() // This "method" is "called" from various
                                 // sections of the LU62XnsCvr program
   {     
     if (mesgcount == 1)
       {
         // On First call Connect the LU62XC Message File 
         FileOutputStream MesgOut = new FileOutputStream(Mesg_File);
         FileChannel MesgChnl = MesgOut.getChannel();
         ByteBuffer Mesg_Bufr = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
       } 

     // Send Message to the Message Log 
     String mesg_str = message_data.toString(); // convert buffer to a string
     MesgWork = mesg_str.getBytes();            // Convert string to byte array 
     Mesg_Bufr.put( MesgWork, bufroffset, MGbuflen );  // copy MesgWork to buffer
     MesgChnl.write( Mesg_Bufr ); // write message buffer out to the file channel
     Mesg_Bufr.clear();
     message_data.append("                "); // set message_data to 16 blanks

     for ( ndx = 0; ndx < MGbuflen; ++ndx )
     {
       MesgWork[ndx] = 0x20; // clear MesgWork byte area using blank character
     }
   }  // End of Send Message log write sub-routine
```

The above looks okay to me; BUT I get the following:

```
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:444: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Mesg_Bufr
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
     Mesg_Bufr.put( MesgWork, bufroffset, MGbuflen );
     ^
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:445: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Mesg_Bufr
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
     MesgChnl.write( Mesg_Bufr ); 
                     ^
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:445: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable MesgChnl
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
     MesgChnl.write( Mesg_Bufr ); 
     ^
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:446: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Mesg_Bufr
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
     Mesg_Bufr.clear(); 
     ^
```

Unless I'm missing something here it appears that `Mesg_Bufr` is "spelled" correctly.
Why can't the compiler "find" the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring `Mesg_Bufr` in the `if` block so it's only visible in that block.

```
if (mesgcount == 1)
{
    //On First call Connect the LU62XC Message File 
    FileOutputStream MesgOut = new FileOutputStream(Mesg_File) ;
    FileChannel MesgChnl  =  MesgOut.getChannel() ;
    ByteBuffer  Mesg_Bufr =  ByteBuffer.allocate(128) ; 
}
```

Same goes for the others. I can't tell what you're trying to do (and tbh I don't care) but to make that run correctly you probably have to put all the code inside the if, or, better yet, return if `mesg != 1`.

Comment: Hmmmm thanks very much ...rather obtuse this compiler and the java language